# After every cron job, the Media tags in WYSIWYG markup change to https upon a robot crawl

Tags: theming, media, cron, wysiwyg, input-formats

My site doesn't use https certificates.

The [Media WYSIWYG markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) changes the images protocol and caches them as https and therefore they don't display as there is no certificate on the website!!

The only thing I could do is re-save the affected pages if I spot them and then it's all good until another robot crawls them again in https after a cron job, which will revert the Media WYSIWYG markup from http to https and we are back to square one.

What is the solution for this?

Can the [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/PATHOLOGIC) module solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want HTTPS, simply turn it off. And if, for some reason, you want HTTPS links to still work, you should [redirect HTTPS to HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http) - but that's out of scope of this site. Just **never leave https on without proper certificate**.

That said, you have some serious bug in your caching configuration, and data you provided is not enough to identify it. Luckily, there is no need to do so.

Comment: the purpose of this question is to avoid robots to change the state of the Media WYSIWYG markup when they crawl the site first after a cron job

Comment: @Mauro robots will only change them only just as users would, so your  "purpose" seems misguided.

Comment: well, usually the robots are faster, but yes, it's not only the robots. the "elephant in the room" that you don't seem to get is why does the http protocol change randomly and how can i block it from doing so. thanks

Answer (score 1):

While you could try rewriting images to HTTP, perhaps easiest to add a free valid SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/howitworks/).

Comment: Mixed security status of various elements is not an ideal solution and may raise red flags in some browsers afair.

Comment: True, but should be ok if on http document with some https elements, else could make the whole site https

Comment: @DavidThomas how would i go to make the whole site https?